# @Value annotation not being properly set

Tags: java, spring, annotations

Here's my app:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);

    //run the importer
    final ImportNewOrders importer = (ImportNewOrders) ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean("importNewOrders");
    importer.run();
    //importer.runInBackground();
}
```

Here's my config:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "com.production"
})
@PropertySource(value = {
        "classpath:/application.properties",
        "classpath:/environment-${MY_ENVIRONMENT}.properties"
})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.fettergroup.production.repositories")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Config {

    .... skipping things that aren't relevant

    @Bean
    public ImportNewOrders importNewOrders() {
        return new ImportNewOrders();
    }
```

Here's my class...

```
@Component
public class ImportNewOrders implements Task {

    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ImportNewOrders.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    private OrderService orderService;

    @Autowired
    private ImportOrderRequest importOrderRequest;

    @Value("${api.user}")
    private String apiUser;

    @Value("${api.password}")
    private String apiPassword;

    @Value("${api.orders.pingFrequency}")
    private String pingFrequency;
```

And finally the `application.properties`:

```
# ------------------- Application settings -------------------

#Base URL to the API application
api.baseUrl=http://localhost:9998

#Unique token used to authenticate this vendor
api.vendor.token=asdf

#API credentials
api.user=myuser
api.password=mypassword

#How often to check for new orders; frequency is in seconds
api.orders.pingFrequency=60
```

This worked an hour or two ago, now it's decided it doesn't like these values.  I'm at a loss as to why.  Everything looks correct to me.

**Update**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "com.production"
})
@PropertySource(value = {
        "classpath:/application.properties",
        "classpath:/environment-${MY_ENVIRONMENT}.properties"
})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.production.repositories")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Config {
    @Value("${db.url}")
    private static String PROPERTY_DATABASE_URL;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();

        dataSource.setUrl(PROPERTY_DATABASE_URL); //is null
        /*dataSource.setUser(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USER));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));*/

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer () {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to help you with everything today. Are the properties not found? Or are you getting some other error?

Comment: lol... the properties are found, I can verify because this file also includes database connection details which is working fine.  I am seeing errors in my code which are a result of `apiPassword = "${api.password}"`

Comment: Are you using `@Value` for the database fields?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your properties file is found by your `@Configuration` and is using it for your database properties within that class because of `@PropertySource`. But `@Value` fields and `${}` evaluation need more than that.

From [Javadoc for `@PropertySource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html)

> In order to resolve ${...} placeholders in  definitions or
>   @Value annotations using properties from a PropertySource, one must
>   register a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer. This happens
>   automatically when using  in XML, but
>   must be explicitly registered using a static @Bean method when using
>   @Configuration classes. See the "Working with externalized values"
>   section of @Configuration Javadoc and "a note on
>   BeanFactoryPostProcessor-returning @Bean methods" of @Bean Javadoc for
>   details and examples.

So declare a

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer p = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    p.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("your properties path"));
    // other properties
    return p;
}
```

in your config class, or as ach has aptly mentioned in the comments if you use `@PropertySource` your can omit `setLocation` altogether:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value="classpath:your_file.properties")
public class MyConfiguration{

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer()    {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer p = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    return p;
    }
}
```

You shouldn't need the environment when you have the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`

> In most cases, however, application-level beans should not need to>
>   interact with the   Environment directly but instead may have to have 
>   ${...} property values replaced by a property placeholder configurer 
>   such as PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer, which itself is 
>   EnvironmentAware and as of Spring 3.1 is registered by default when 
>   using < context:property-placeholder/>.

Comment: You don't even need to set the location, you can just `return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer()` as long as you have `@PropertySources` pointing at your properties files.

Comment: Sweet, I did not know this.

Comment: When I add a bean for this, it no longer autowires `Environment environment;` into my config class.

Comment: @Webnet See above, unless you are using Environment for something else, properties are now available with `@Value` because of `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`. Update your post with full (or parts) configuration.

Comment: Read this answer too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169834/spring-3-1-environment-does-not-work-with-user-property-files

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - I've updated my configuration.  I was only using `Environment` for the properties.  If I understand this correctly, I don't need to specify a location for my properties files because it should be loaded from the `@PropertySource` annotation.  When I do try to specify a location anyways, I use `p.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("classpath:/application.properties"));` and it says it can't find it.  But that error doesn't appear when that path is used in `@PropertySource`

Comment: @Webnet So don't use it. For the ClassPathResource, I don't think you need to specify the `classpath:` prefix.

Comment: I've read through the documentation and I'm doing everything according to their examples...

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - At the end of my post you'll see my current config.  I'm trying to get `@Value("${db.url}")` mapped to a value.  When I implement `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` as you mentioned it's null, when I don't implement that bean it becomes a string, with the value of `"${db.url}"`

Comment: @Webnet Try to make the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean method `static`. You're on Spring 3.1+?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - That did it... Thank You!!  I'm on 3.2.1