# Why can't @Value inject a JNDI value from the Environment?

Tags: spring, tomcat, jndi

I'm having trouble injecting JNDI values from my Tomcat into spring java config using the `@Value` annotation whereas I have no trouble retreiving the values via the [`Environment`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) class. We are using Java 1.7.0_17, Spring 4.0.3, and Tomcat 7.0.52 .

I have in my `context.xml` the following variables defined:

```xml
<Environment name="USER_NAME" value="initech" type="java.lang.String" />
<Environment name="USER_PASSWORD" value="1n3+3ch!" type="java.lang.String" />
```

In my Java configuration file I have the following code ***working***:

```
@Bean
public Foo foo( Environment env ){
    return new Foo( env.getProperty("USER_NAME"), env.getProperty("USER_PASSWORD") );
}
```

When I look into the server log I see:

```
12:50:45.214 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver -> Searching for key 'USER_NAME' in [servletConfigInitParams]
12:50:45.214 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver -> Searching for key 'USER_NAME' in [servletContextInitParams]
12:50:45.214 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver -> Searching for key 'USER_NAME' in [jndiProperties]
12:50:45.214 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate -> Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/USER_NAME]
12:50:45.214 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate -> Located object with JNDI name [java:comp/env/USER_NAME]
12:50:45.214 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.jndi.JndiPropertySource -> JNDI lookup for name [USER_NAME] returned: [initech]
12:50:45.214 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver -> Found key 'USER_NAME' in [jndiProperties] with type [String] and value 'initech'
```

However, I would like to use `@Value` annotation to make the code cleaner if at all possible; something along the lines of

```
@Bean
public Foo foo(
        @Value( "#{USER_NAME}" ) String userName,
        @Value( "#{USER_PASSWORD}" ) String userPassword
    ){

    return new Foo( userName, userPassword );
}
```

but this code results in the error:

```
nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'USER_NAME' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'USER_NAME' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'oauthTokenRequestClient' defined in class path resource [com/initech/set/gw/api/config/GatewayRepositoryConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.net.URI]: : Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'USER_NAME' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'USER_NAME' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:747)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:462)
```

I have tried `"#{systemEnvironment.USER_NAME}`, `"#{systemProperties.USER_NAME}`, `"#{jndiProperties.USER_NAME}`, and `"#{java:comp/env/USER_NAME}` as well: yet, none of them work.

PS- I've tried to simplify the question so if one of these *should* have worked let me know because I may have made an error in my posting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Spring: How to use \`@Value\` annotation to inject an \`Environment\` property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617181/java-spring-how-to-use-value-annotation-to-inject-an-environment-property)

Comment: @Morfic yeah, it pretty much is. Must have missed it since I was searching for "JNDI" and not "Environment". This question should still help people like myself in the future if it doesn't get deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it using [the selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14617182/254477) from the question [Java Spring: How to use `@Value` annotation to inject an `Environment` property?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14617181/254477).

So my code looks like:

```
@Bean
public Foo foo(
        @Value( "#{environment.USER_NAME}" ) String userName,
        @Value( "#{environment.USER_PASSWORD}" ) String userPassword
    ){

    return new Foo( userName, userPassword );
}
```

I'm assuming from the content of [the most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14617285/254477) (ie "assuming that you have a `PropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer` registered") to that quesiton that this means we are lacking a configured `PropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring 4 you should change

```
  @Value( "#{USER_PASSWORD}" ) String userPassword
```

To

```
@Value( "${USER_PASSWORD}" ) String userPassword
```

Try that and see what happens.

Comment: `@Value("#{environment.USER_NAME}")` worked for me whereas `@Value("${USER_NAME}")` did not. The types I'm actually using are `URI` and with `@Value("${USER_NAME}")` I get an exception from the `URI` constructor that "$" is an invalid character which suggest it took the literal value when using the `$`.

Comment: When using `${…}` placeholders you have to register a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfiguere` else it will not work. This registration has to be done with a `public static` method which is annotated with `@Bean`. See the accepted answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15395123/value-annotation-not-being-properly-set

Answer (score 1):

For Spring 3.1+ (tested on 4.2.5.RELEASE), you can use `@Value` like this:

```
@Value("${property.name}")
private String jndiProperty;
```

But you also need to define a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean in a `static` method **and** configure a `JndiPropertySource` (I have this in an `@Configuration` class):

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer(ConfigurableEnvironment env) {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();

    JndiPropertySource jndiPropertySource = new JndiPropertySource("java:comp");
    env.getPropertySources().addFirst(jndiPropertySource);

    return placeholderConfigurer;
}
```

Note the use of `addFirst()` which ensures property values from JNDI take precedence in case of a clash with other property sources, which may or may not be desired, in which case one can use other methods like `addLast()` etc.

Answer (score -2):

This is the correct syntex

```
  @Value("${PASSWORD}")
```

Have a look at this example:

http://www.programsji.com/spring/readpropertyfile

Comment: But it's not coming from a property file but from a JNDI value from the `context.xml` of my container _and_ I have already tried that and it didn't work.